Getting Arista drop counts via snmp
My group's R&D lab has an Arista 10G switch, DCS-7020SR-24C2. My admin (who is not a switch expert) enabled SNMP access. I want to see per-port drop counters.
I tried this:
 snmpwalk -v 2c -c community 10.29.4.252

and I get almost 11k lines, some of which contain the word "Drop". However, they are all stuck at zero.
I did an experiment where two hosts send packets to the same multicast group/port, each sending about 9.5 gbps. Naturally the subscriber only got about half the total packets sent. But none of the counters in the snmpwalk output went above zero. Specifically:
 SNMPv2-MIB::snmpSilentDrops.0 = Counter32: 0
 SNMPv2-MIB::snmpProxyDrops.0 = Counter32: 0
 ...
 RMON-MIB::etherStatsDropEvents.1 = Counter32: 0
 RMON-MIB::etherStatsDropEvents.2 = Counter32: 0
 RMON-MIB::etherStatsDropEvents.3 = Counter32: 0
 RMON-MIB::etherStatsDropEvents.4 = Counter32: 0
 ...

I suspect I need to specify which MIB to get, but when I look at https://www.arista.com/en/support/product-documentation/arista-snmp-mibs I turn pale and want to hide under my bed, especially since it doesn't even have links for the "standard" MIBs.
For what it's worth, the above snmpwalk command output included data from the following:
 DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::
 EtherLike-MIB::
 HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::
 IF-MIB::
 IP-FORWARD-MIB::
 IP-MIB::
 NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB::
 RMON-MIB::
 SNMPv2-MIB::
 SNMPv2-SMI::
 TCP-MIB::
 UDP-MIB::

How do I use snmpwalk to get at port drop counts caused by oversubscription?

I would start with the interface MIB, IF-MIB.

@RonMaupin Thank you! Add that as a solution so I can vote on it. I was looking for "Drop". Your hint prompted me to find "Discard", and that appears to be the right one.

OK, I did that.

It would seem most likely to me that per-interface statistics would be found using the (interface) IF-MIB.
It appears you found the discard counters in there, and that would seem to be what you were really looking for. Management tools, e.g. SolarWinds, also use the discard terminology for when an interface queue is full and frames need to be dropped because they cannot be queued.

Good old vocabulary. NIC vendors tend to use the term "drop", and I'm mostly a socket programmer, so that's what I went with. When you narrowed it down to one MIB, I was able to just skim through it and saw "discard". Thanks.
